# Cloning a Windows partition through unix

Tags: windows-7, unix, multi-boot, dd

my boot disk has chameleon installed with a linux partition and a second, empty partition that I would like to use with Windows7.

Since you never know how much things will Win7 ruin when installing I would like to remove that boot hdd, install Win7 on an empty hdd (that I already have) and then clone it to the second partition of first disk and boot through Chameleon (which will auto recognize it) without having worries about MBRs or boot loaders.

My first though was using simply `dd` to clone the windows7 partition to the other drive but I'm wondering if it will work without any worries..

any suggestions?

EDIT: forgot to mention, of course I'm able to write and read NTFS partitions from linux

Answer (score 0):

I've only attempted to do this once and it failed miserably (with windows XP at the time). i wanted to do the same exact method as yours but ended up switching the order.

I installed win7 on the extra hdd and created a 2nd partition that i dd'd over a copy of my linux installation. I found it MUCH easier to put grub in the MBR and modify all of linux's paths (fstab hda2 vs hda1 as before and the such) instead of windows.

From what I understand, windows likes to me the first partition on the boot drive, makes things annoying but still doable.